# How can I generate :attributes_for an already created Factory?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

**Update (Don't answer this)**

I just learned that this question doesn't actually make sense. It was based on my own misconception of Factories and how they work.

---

The whole idea was based on a misconception of how FactoryBot works, in particular for some reason I was thinking that FactoryBot was setting a few variables that a completely different gem (Devise) was actually responsible for.

Is there any easy way to access the 'virtual attributes' for an already built factory?

Something like :attributes_for, but used on an instance of a Factory instead of the class?

So you could do something like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { "password" }
    password_confirmation { "password" }
  end
end

@user = FactoryBot.build(:user)

@user.factory_attributes # Not a real method
#-> { email: "name@gmail.com", password: "123456", password_confirmation: "123456" }
```

---

**Why I Want This**

If you're wondering, I want this to be able to shorten the following code for a 'Login' request spec.

From this:

```
let(:user_attributes) do
  FactoryBot.attributes_for(:user)
end

let(:user) do
  FactoryBot.create(:user, user_attributes)
end

# Triggers the create method in let(:user)
# Necessary to ensure the user exists in the database before testing sign in.
before { user } 

let(:user_params) do 
  { user: user_attributes }
end

it "redirects to the root path on successful sign in" do
  post user_session_path(params: user_params)
  expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
end
```

To this:

```
let(:user) do
  FactoryBot.create(:user)
end

let(:user_params) do 
  { user: user.factory_attributes }
end

it "redirects to the root path on successful sign in" do
  post user_session_path(params: user_params)
  expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
end
```

Which is significantly cleaner and less confusing than the first, especially for newer devs (could see someone with little RSpec experience spending quite some time trying to figure out just what in the hell the line "before { user }" is doing)

Comment: Why not use `let!(:user)` this forces invocation before each example.

Comment: "I want to shorten to this" - in that snippet, `user_attributes` is not defined. And if you add it, code becomes just about the same length and complexity as the other snippet.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, right, my hope is that something like "user.factory_attributes" (which isn't a real method) could be used to replace the need for explicitly defining the attributes.

Comment: @JoshHadik: what? That would make those two declarations mutually dependent (and therefore impossible).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's my bad, I forgot to remove the user_attributes variable from when I copied the let(:user) statement. Just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any easy way to access the 'virtual attributes' for an already built factory?

I think you are confused about terminology and/or how factory bot works. You don't build **factories**. Factory already exists and it builds **users** (in this case).

After a user is built/created, it has no knowledge of what factory built it. And rightly so. Users can be created in many ways. If that method did actually exist, what would you expect it to return when you create a user with `User.create`?

Comment: Yeah no your right. The whole idea was based on a misconception of how FactoryBot works, in particular for some reason I was thinking that FactoryBot was setting a few variables that a completely different gem (Devise) was actually responsible for. Goes to show the 'magic' of Rails can screw you over if you get lazy with it. Thanks. While this didn't specifically answer my question (which I now realize made no sense in the first place,) it did help me out a lot in understanding how FactoryBot actually works, so I'll set this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

`FactoryBot.build(:user)` returns an instance of an `ActiveRecord` model. Therefore you can just use [`ActiveRecord::Base#attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) to return the list of attributes of the current object:

```
@user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
@user.attributes
```

Once the factory returned an instance of `User` that `user` has no information anymore about how it was initialized. Therefore it is impossible to read values that do not exist on the instance.

A workaround might be something like this:

```
let(:parameters) do
  { user: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:user) }
end

before do
  FactoryBot.create(:user, parameters[:user])
end

it "redirects to the root path on successful sign in" do
  post user_session_path(params: parameters)
  expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
end
```

But actually, I think you should be more explicit about what attributes you really care about. You care about the user's email and user's password - all other attributes are not relevant in this spec. Therefore I would write the spec like this:

```
let(:email) { 'foobar@example.tld' }
let(:password) { 'secret' }

before do
  FactoryBot.create(:user, email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: password)
end

it "redirects to the root path on successful sign in" do
  post user_session_path(params: { user: { email: email, password: password } })
  expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
end
```

Comment: However this might need a bit of cleaning given id, timestamps, etc. would be included in `attributes` where as `attributes_for` will just be a `Hash` of the factory defined attributes

Comment: Normally, this works. The problem is that I'm trying to access virtual attributes from  Factory that don't actually exist on the User model ('password' and 'password_confirmation,') and #attributes only returns the actual attributes defined in the ActiveRecord model

Comment: @JoshHadik I updated my answer to address your comment.